# Can I say お兄さんは結婚いたしております?

Tags: grammar, keigo

Can I say

> お兄さんは結婚いたしております

instead of

> お兄さんは結婚しております

Comment: With keigo, it is possible to overdo things.  If you overdo the keigo you can obfuscate the sentence so much the the listener can no longer understand what it is you are saying/trying to say.

Comment: I am assuming you're talking about your own elder brother, so 兄{あに} would be a better word choice than お兄さん{おにいさん}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"いたす" is used for what "I" (the speaker) do when the opponent is superior. It is called "謙譲語".　If you're talking about the brother of others, you should not use this.

If you're talking about your own brother, you may say "兄は結婚いたしております".